# Сергея и Юлию Скрипаль или Сергея и Юлию Скрипалей?

Tags: фамилии

Сергея и Юлию Скрипаль или Сергея и Юлию Скрипалей?

На Грамоте:

Подавляющее большинство русских фамилий имеет формальные показатели — суффиксы -ов- (-ев-), -ин-, -ск-: Лермонтов, Тургенев, Пушкин, Достоевский, Крамской.

Нерусские фамилии, относящиеся к двум или нескольким лицам, в одних случаях ставятся в форме множественного числа, в других – в форме единственного:

3) если фамилия сопровождается мужским и женским именами, то она сохраняет форму единственного числа, например: Франклин и Элеонора Рузвельт, Рональд и Нэнси Рейган, Ариадна и Петр Тур, Нина и Станислав Жук;

Но Жук - разве не русская фамилия? Или не склоняется она при мужском и женском имени, потому что фамилия Жук, называющая лицо женского рода, не склоняется?

Answer (score 1):

Вы ведь сами нашли ответ. Если такая фамилия сопровождается мужским и женским именами, то она сохраняет форму единственного числа: **Сергея и Юлию Скрипаль**.

Answer (score 1):

В написании ***Сергея и Юлию Скрипаль/Скрипалей*** (В.п.) наблюдается колебание.

Это связано с тем, что **фамилия склоняется во множественном числе** https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Skripal/skloneniye.html?familiya=%D1%EA%F0%E8%EF%E0%EB%FC

**У Розенталя:**  [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#з_02](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_02)

10. Нерусские фамилии, относящиеся к двум или нескольким лицам, **в одних случаях ставятся в форме множественного числа, в других – в форме единственного:**

3)      если фамилия сопровождается **мужским и женским именами, то она сохраняет форму единственного числа,** например: Франклин и Элеонора Рузвельт, Рональд и Нэнси Рейган, Ариадна и Петр Тур, Нина и Станислав Жук;

4)      в единственном числе ставится также фамилия, если она сопровождается **двумя нарицательными существительными**, указывающими на разный пол, например: господин и госпожа Клинтон, лорд и леди Гамильтон; **однако при сочетаниях муж и жена, брат и сестра фамилия чаще употребляется в форме множественного числа: муж и жена Эстремы, брат и сестра Ниринги;**

7)      при слове семья фамилия **обычно** ставится в форме единственного числа, например: семья Оппенгейм, семья Гофман-сталь.

В нашем же случае ***семья Скрипалей*** склоняется, к тому же это отец и дочь Скрипали.

Поэтому в И.п. обычно пишут ***Сергей и Юлия Скрипаль***, а в В.п. встречаются **оба варианта**.